# What information does the Weight matrix provide?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I am dealing with binary classification problem. I just printed a part of the code. I am familiar with softmax function that it gives probability of belonging to certain class. At W_fc I can not get any information about classes. So I was wondering what information does W_fc provide? What is the significance of the values printed in W_fc? Can I plot histogram of W_fc? How I will do that?

```
W_fc = weight_variable([input_dim, 2])
logits = tf.matmul(pool_2D, W_fc)   #(batch_size,2)
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(logits)

#Fully connected layer(W_fc)
[[-0.07672054  0.2260601 ]
[ 0.36111656 -0.36078873]
[ 0.08611391 -0.23779725]
[-0.07158212 -0.21373497]

#softmax_out(y_conv)
[[0.80258745 0.19741252]
[0.76372457 0.23627539]
[0.8738684  0.12613155]
[0.7311098  0.26889023]
```

Comment: Weight matrix is *not* meant for such kind of information, and it is normally not meant for histograms etc (apart from viewing the distribution of your weights for general diagnostic purposes - see [Tensorboard](https://jhui.github.io/2017/03/12/TensorBoard-visualize-your-learning/))

Comment: Then what these values represent? These weight matrix provide weight of which parameter? Can we use it  W along x axis and frequecy along y-axis to plot histogram?

Comment: They represent the weight of the "connections" between subsequent network layers - explained lucidly in dozens of tutorials available online... As for your histogram idea, you certainly can (from a programming point of view), but what exactly for?

Comment: Hey guys. Doesn't this question belong to stats.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

`W_fc` here most likely refers to the matrix of `W`eights associated with the `f`ully `c`onnected layer of your neural network. For a simple digestible explanation of what function these perform see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk).

The values of these weights essentially define the behaviour of your neural network, and achieving a good configuration of these values is the exact problem we aim to solve during the training process for neural networks. The training process gradually adjusts these values via back-propagation to increase network performance on the training data, in the hope that the information encoded in these weights holds true in the face of new data.

As for "what information `W_fc` provides?". To you the user: not much. Well at least not in an observable form. The interactions between these weights and how they contribute to network performance are complex in all but the simplest networks.

In convolution neural networks (CNNs) the values in the weights are somewhat more digestible due to the spatially local nature of the weight connections. And in these cases groups of these weights act as feature detectors of increasing complexity as you progess deeper into the network ([see here](https://indico.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cnn_deeper.jpg)).

In terms of histogramming the values, you can certainly do that, (see [matplotlib.hist()](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html)). But little useful information is provided by this. Although there are arguments that lower values in the weights provide better generalisation to new data (the basis of [regularisation](https://cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE574/Chap5/Chap5.5-Regularization.pdf)) and that any dominantly high-valued weights can be evidence of [overtraining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: If my W matrix  shape is (50,2) and shape of one hot vector at a particular temperature is (2,1) and I perform matrix like multiplication b/w two then what information it will give me about that particular temperature?

Comment: I am familiar with back propagation. According to my understanding positive values in W matrix means nodes with which they are connected are more significant. But I am not sure if my understanding is correct. I am particularly dealing with CNN

Comment: "I am familiar with back propagation. According to my understanding positive values in W matrix means nodes with which they are connected are more significant" - This is true.

Comment: See the configuration of a [perceptron](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*n6sJ4yZQzwKL9wnF5wnVNg.png) (basic NN unit). Values in W refer to the weights by which inputs are multiplied. Greater positive values in W increases the "weighted sum".

Comment: The exact affect depends on the [activation function](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6), for most CNNs this is relu. For which the "significance" of the node (or the magnitude of its output) increases linearly with this weighted sum.

Comment: As for the shape of W being (50,2), this is a bit unusual. As W is called `W_fc` I am expecting it to be the weights for the "fully connected" layer. Typically these weights are a 1D array of length = number of nodes in that layer. 

Typically Convolution layers are of higher dimensionality, arranged into tensors of (node_number x filter_height x filter_width). The filters here are locally connected weights and their heights and width are typically small (3x3 or 5x5), and stacked layers of these filters build more advance network complexity.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain one more thing. If I'm performing 1D convolution on CNN. filter width is 2. Now I want to extract the information how the 1st two values of input are related. Can I do that from W matrix?Can I extract information about convolution?

Comment: Okay, so if you are doing 1D convolution then W shape (50,2) makes sense. (Though I would rename `W_fc` to `W_conv` or clarity as it is the convolution layer). 

As for the information you want it depends on what you mean by "are related". The filters you learn do not represent any particular pair of inputs. Each of your 50, length 2 filters is convolved (multiplied)  with __every__ adjacent pair of inputs. The filters themselves adapt to build representations of your inputs in increasing complexity over several layers.

Comment: The only information you can gain about how input1 relates to input2 would be to train the network, then from your learned filters see which filters produce the highest activation in the locality of input1 and input2. This activation would be the output of the convolution operation, but all it would tell you would be which filters these inputs are causing to activate.